# In what manner are values added to a list in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have been getting this problem when trying to retrieve data from the database: I save the data into 'new recipe' and then add that to the list, however, whenever I try to get the value from an index in that list, it says it is out of index range in logcat(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1), even though the index is 1. This leads me to ask: When adding to a list in this way, are all the variables stored in one item in the list rather than 8 separate ones?

Here's the code for reading and adding to the list (inDBHelper Class):

```
 public List<RecipeModel> readRecipe() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<RecipeModel> returnRecipe = new ArrayList<>();

        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + RECIPE_TABLE;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        cursor.moveToLast();
        int recipeID = cursor.getInt(0);
        String recipeName = cursor.getString(1);
        String recipeCountry = cursor.getString( 2);
        String recipeHours = cursor.getString(3);
        String recipeMinutes = cursor.getString(4);
        String recipeEquipment = cursor.getString(5);
        String recipeIngredients = cursor.getString(6);
        String recipeMethod = cursor.getString(7);
        String recipeStory = cursor.getString(8);

        RecipeModel newRecipe = new RecipeModel(recipeID, recipeName, recipeCountry, recipeHours, recipeMinutes, recipeEquipment, recipeIngredients, recipeMethod, recipeStory);

        returnRecipe.add(newRecipe);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnRecipe;

    }
```

Here is the code that is trying to get the value from the list index (in Main Activity):

```
 DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(preview_recipe.this);
        //call read function and array
        List<RecipeModel> returnRecipe = dbHelper.readRecipe();

        //Setting values into text views
        viewRecipeName.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(1));
        viewCountry.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(2));
        viewTxtHours.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(3));
        viewMins.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(4));
        viewTxtEquipment.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(5));
        viewTxtIngredients.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(6));
        viewTxtMethod.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(7));
        viewPersonalStory.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(8));
```

RecipeModel (excluding getters and setters) :

```
public class RecipeModel {
    private int id;
    private String recipeName;
    private String recipeCountry;
    private String recipeHours;
    private String recipeMinutes;
    private String recipeEquipment;
    private String recipeIngredients;
    private String recipeMethod;
    private String recipeStory;

    public RecipeModel(int id, String recipeName, String recipeCountry, String recipeHours, String recipeMinutes, String recipeEquipment, String recipeIngredients, String recipeMethod, String recipeStory) {
        this.id = id;
        this.recipeName = recipeName;
        this.recipeCountry = recipeCountry;
        this.recipeHours = recipeHours;
        this.recipeMinutes = recipeMinutes;
        this.recipeEquipment = recipeEquipment;
        this.recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients;
        this.recipeMethod = recipeMethod;
        this.recipeStory = recipeStory;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RecipeModel{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", recipeName='" + recipeName + '\'' +
                ", recipeCountry='" + recipeCountry + '\'' +
                ", recipeHours='" + recipeHours + '\'' +
                ", recipeMinutes='" + recipeMinutes + '\'' +
                ", recipeEquipment='" + recipeEquipment + '\'' +
                ", recipeIngredients='" + recipeIngredients + '\'' +
                ", recipeMethod='" + recipeMethod + '\'' +
                ", recipeStory='" + recipeStory + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Comment: Lists and Arrays in Java/ANdroind are 0 based. So the first value is always at index 0 not index 1.

Comment: @sorifiend Will it matter if I choose not to call the value at index 0 and skip right onto 1?

Comment: You could, however, it looks like you only ever add a single `RecipeModel` to your list. Please edit your question to include the RecipeModel class, however, I assume that you want to get the inner contents of that item, so you would need to use something like `returnRecipe.get(0).get(...)` or `returnRecipe.get(0).getRecipeName();`

Comment: IMO ``readRecipe`` shouldn't really be returning a list at all, since it explicitly only returns a single ``RecipeModel``. And yeah, it should definitely expose properties with ``getName()`` etc, no magic numbers like ``get(1)``!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `List<RecipeModel> readRecipe()` return a List who contain a single `RecipeModel`.

You should write :

```
        viewRecipeName.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(0).getName());
        viewCountry.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(0).getCountry());
        viewTxtHours.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.get(0).getTxtHours());
        ...
```

If you need just to fill the informations of a single RecipeModel , change the helper Method return type is better , i suggest that you make it return a RecipeModel not a List of RecipeModels.

Comment: Note that your `RecipeModel` class will need to have methods named `getName`, `getCountry` etc for this to work, but this is the correct solution. If the variable inside the `RecipeModel` class are public then you can also reference them directly `viewRecipeName.setText((CharSequence) returnRecipe.name);`

Comment: @sorifiend making the variables public is not a good choice. There, you share the reference ad that can be dangerous as the value can be changed